# Is this equation in the image solvable?

Tags: integration

I saw this image as a joke, and wondered if the equation can be solved. Can anyone perhaps assist with a solution?

[image]

Disclaimer: The note is fictional. I do not have access to the card in the picture, and am not seeking to find a pin code for any card. I am merely interested if the equation can be solved. If someone can just confirm that it is indeed solveable and works out to a valid value without giving the actual answer, that would be enough for me.

Comment: The problem is that there is not any equation to solve!

Comment: So.. its an integral. But without the bounds you'll only get another function

Comment: @TheIntegrator: Actually it's not an integral – there's no integral sign... But since you're The Integrator, you can probably integrate it anyway. :-)

Comment: @HansLundmark i guessed it was an integral cus of the $dx$ at the end.I might be the integrator .... but alas , there are some  hurdles even I cannot cross.......

Comment: @TheIntegrator: Of course, whoever wrote that probably *meant* an integral. (Or they copied an integral without knowing what they were doing and left out the integral sign. Or wrote the integral sign with invisible ink. Or something else. Hard to tell, really...)

Comment: @HansLundmark yeah you're right. also I've always wanted to say this .

**Hans, get ze flammenwerfer**

Comment: @TheIntegrator: OK, I've got it! Is there any particular post you want me to apply it to? :-)

Comment: @HansLundmark Omg i luv ya, applying it to my UG entrance paper would be absolutely fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Whoever wrote this is clearly not very good at math, since they put an $x^2$ twice, and an ambiguous "equation". I'm going to make an assumption that the problem is actually an integral

$$ I = \int \frac{x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 1}{x^2 - 4x + 4} dx $$

Performing long division on the integrand

$$ \frac{x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 1}{x^2 - 4x + 4} = x + 1 + \frac{2x-5}{x^2-4x+4} $$

Then partial fractions

$$ x + 1 + \frac{2x-5}{x^2-4x+4} = x + 1 + \frac{2(x-2) - 1}{(x-2)^2}  = x + 1 + \frac{2}{x-2} - \frac{1}{(x-2)^2} $$
Integrating the above gives

$$ I = \frac{x^2}{2} + x + 2\ln|x-2| + \frac{1}{x-2} + C $$

Overall, it's pretty straightforward.